# Django: how to get input from one function to another function under views?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am a rookie for django and I know my question is very basic. I want to design a web application with two functions. The first function can let user to input a wav audio file name at home page. And the second function can read this audio file and analyze the audio signal and make fft plot. My each function works fine if I run individually, I just don't know how can I let my second function read the filename got from first function.

This is my first function for input filename.

```
def home(request):
  form = EmailForm(request.POST or None)
  if form.is_valid():
        print form.cleaned_data['filename']
  context = {"form": form}
  template = "home.html"
  return render(request, template, context)
```

This is part of my second function:

```
def fftsound(request):
  from scipy import fft, arange, ifft
  from scipy.io import wavfile
  form = EmailForm(request.POST or None)
  if request.method == 'POST':    
      print "POST"
      if form.is_valid():
            print "valid"
            filename = form.cleaned_data.get('filename')
  else:
     form = EmailForm()
  rate,data=wavfile.read(filename)
```

My form looks like this:

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
  filename = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
```

And my models looks like this:

```
class application(models.Model):
  filename= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s" %(self.filename)
```

Now if I only run my first function, I can get the correct print on my terminal. I just don't know how to apply this input on my second function. Can any one help me with this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your first function

```
return fftsound(request, filename)
```

in your second function,

```
def fftsound(request, filename):
```

change the last line to

```
return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: You mean delete the last line in the first function and change it to `return fftsound(request, filename)` ? I tried but it said unindent does not match any outer indentation level. it's weird, I don't understand this error. I also tried add filename in my original return render, it said no global variable filename. Can you explain more? I really don't know django, thank you!

Comment: To clarify it a bit: in first function place ```return fftsound(request, form.cleaned_data['filename'])``` instead of ```print...```. Add ```filename``` argument to second function and return html response at the end (```return render(request, template, context)```).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use something like this for home view:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                app = application.objects.create(filename=form.cleaned_data['filename'])

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/fft/{}/'.format(app.id))

    form = EmailForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

This will save filename to the database, so you can read it later, and redirect user to next url (which is unique for every file - `/fft/<file_id>`).

You will also have to save actual file to the database? Or better: save it to the disk and reference it in the database. Read [THIS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#filefield) for mor information.

Next step is to add entry to your `urls.py` file to handle this new url. It will look something like:

```
url(r'^fft/(?P<file_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.fftsound),
```

With this you will give extra parameter (`file_id`) to `fftsound` function. So you will have to modify it a bit.

```
def fftsound(request, file_id):
    app = application.objects.get(id=file_id)
    ...
```

And you will have filename in `app.filename` and file in `app.fftfile` (or something similar - as I mentioned you will have to add this part). And you can do with them whatever you want.

Whit this method you can always come back and see fft plot of already uploads files (just go to lets say `/fft/42/`). So you will have to add some kind of access control if don't want that all files are public.